# actionPerformed using multiple JTextField's

Tags: java, swing

How do I assign the JTextFields to different variables in my actionListener if I have them coded like this? I have to create a mortgage calculator so in my actionPerformed method I am stuck I need to save these textfield values into a variable so I can use them for calculations

```
mortgFields.add(new JTextField("165000", 10));
  mortgFields.add(new JTextField("30", 10));
  mortgFields.add(new JTextField("360", 10));
  mortgFields.add(new JTextField("7", 10));
  mortgFields.add(new JTextField("109.75", 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection. For example a List.

```
List<JTextField> list = Arrays.asList(new JTextField("165000", 10),new JTextField("30", 10));

// and then in some place
for (JTextField textfield : list)
{
    mortgFields.add(textfield);
}
```

You can access by index, with `list.get(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try for loop:

```
for(String txt: new String[]{"165000", "30", "360", "7", "109.75"}) {
  mortgFields.add(new JTextField(txt, 10));
}
```